# PHP SOAP Server - how to check parameters against WSDL file

Tags: php, soap, parameters

I'm setting up a SOAP service using the PHP SOAP server and client library.
I've coded some structured data types into my wsdl file with some heavy restrictions.
Do you know of functionality in the PHP SOAP library or of a 3rd party library which will check the actual parameters in the the server against the definitions of the WSDL file? Or do I have to code all my parameter checking explicitly into my SOAP server class, even though it is already coded in the WSDL?

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 5.2 the SOAP server does not validate against the WSDL as described here http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45966
I'm not sure about 5.3 though.

Comment: Thank you, but this is exactly my problem and not the solution.